# Can't Find Regulator for 16G CO2 Cartridge (800 PSI to 400-200PSI)

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, compressed-air

I am trying to make a Paintball Gun that works off of 16G CO2 Cartridges(800 PSI). I can't find a compact regulator that drops 800 PSI down to 400-200 PSI. If anyone knows of such a regulator could you please comment it below?
Also I wanted to try using a [Ninja Regulator](https://www.ansgear.com/Ninja_Adjustable_Tank_Regulator_4500_PSI_p/ninjatank-reg45.htm?gclid=CjwKCAiArIH_BRB2EiwALfbH1O6Qn36cHBuKaCc27EQ2pVf4dSfHIpTaW3vfSBXtD57bdY8dI9FIsBoCz6MQAvD_BwE), but I don't know if the 4500 PSI or 3000 PSI input pressure would work with 800 PSI.

Comment: Can you call Ninja and ask them? It may work but at reduced flow through the regulator or not work at all.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try asking!